# Lucene: Norwegian Analyser - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.lucene.analysis.WordlistLoader.getSnowballWordSet

Tags: hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I am getting exception while deployment of project having newly implemented Norwegian Analyser

```
@Fields({ @Field(index = Index.YES, store = Store.YES, analyzer = @Analyzer(impl=NorwegianAnalyzer.class))
```

Detailed Stack trace of error is :

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.search.SearchException: Failed to instantiate lucene analyzer with type org.apache.lucene.analysis.no.NorwegianAnalyzer
        at org.hibernate.search.engine.impl.AnnotationProcessingHelper.getAnalyzer(AnnotationProcessingHelper.java:170)
        at org.hibernate.search.engine.impl.FieldMetadata.<init>(FieldMetadata.java:94)
        at org.hibernate.search.engine.spi.AbstractDocumentBuilder.bindFieldAnnotation(AbstractDocumentBuilder.java:1085)
        at org.hibernate.search.engine.spi.AbstractDocumentBuilder.checkForFields(AbstractDocumentBuilder.java:552)
        at org.hibernate.search.engine.spi.AbstractDocumentBuilder.initializeMemberLevelAnnotations(AbstractDocumentBuilder.java:485)
        at org.hibernate.search.engine.spi.AbstractDocumentBuilder.initializeClass(AbstractDocumentBuilder.java:392)
        at org.hibernate.search.engine.spi.AbstractDocumentBuilder.<init>(AbstractDocumentBuilder.java:174)
        at org.hibernate.search.engine.spi.DocumentBuilderContainedEntity.<init>(DocumentBuilderContainedEntity.java:60)
        at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchFactoryBuilder.initDocumentBuilders(SearchFactoryBuilder.java:396)
        at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchFactoryBuilder.buildNewSearchFactory(SearchFactoryBuilder.java:222)
        at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchFactoryBuilder.buildSearchFactory(SearchFactoryBuilder.java:146)
        at org.hibernate.search.event.impl.FullTextIndexEventListener.initialize(FullTextIndexEventListener.java:130)
        at org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.HibernateSearchIntegrator.integrate(HibernateSearchIntegrator.java:83)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:306)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1797)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:96)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:899)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:76)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:268)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
        ... 42 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.search.SearchException: Unable to instantiate analyzer class: org.apache.lucene.analysis.no.NorwegianAnalyzer. Verify it has a no-args public constructor and is not abstract. Also Analyzer implementation classes or their tokenStream() and reusableTokenStream() implementations must be final.
        at org.hibernate.search.util.impl.ClassLoaderHelper.analyzerInstanceFromClass(ClassLoaderHelper.java:234)
        at org.hibernate.search.engine.impl.AnnotationProcessingHelper.getAnalyzer(AnnotationProcessingHelper.java:161)
        ... 64 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at org.hibernate.search.util.impl.ClassLoaderHelper.analyzerInstanceFromClass(ClassLoaderHelper.java:215)
        ... 65 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.lucene.analysis.WordlistLoader.getSnowballWordSet(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/Set;
        at org.apache.lucene.analysis.no.NorwegianAnalyzer$DefaultSetHolder.<clinit>(NorwegianAnalyzer.java:65)
        at org.apache.lucene.analysis.no.NorwegianAnalyzer.<init>(NorwegianAnalyzer.java:79)
```

Any idea how to resolve the same?

Answer (score 0):

The `org.apache.lucene.analysis.no.NorwegianAnalyzer` mentioned in the stacktrace seems to not match the expected version of `org.apache.lucene.analysis.WordlistLoader`.

Since in recent versions of Apache Lucene both classes are included in the same jar, it seems likely that you have some duplicate versions of Lucene jars in your classpath.

Make sure to use only jars from the Apache Lucene version matching the version expected by Hibernate Search.